# Verilog Error - Quartus II - Loop Must terminate within X iterations

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

I am working on a VERY simple verilog implementation of a RiSC16 CPU, and I am running into an issue trying compile using Quartus II Web Edition.  My code is below:

```
reg j;
initial begin
pc = 0;
rf[0] = `ZERO;
rf[1] = `ZERO;
rf[2] = `ZERO;
rf[3] = `ZERO;
rf[4] = `ZERO;
rf[5] = `ZERO;
rf[6] = `ZERO;
rf[7] = `ZERO;
    for(j=0;j<200;j=j+1) begin // THis is line 38
        m[j] = 16'd0; 
    end
end
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error (10106): Verilog HDL Loop error at RiSC16.v(38): loop must terminate within 10000 iterations
```

I am quite lost at this point.  Has anyone experienced this before? Is there a syntax error somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `j` is declared as 1-bit, its only values are 0 and 1; it cannot reach 200, and the `for` loop will be infinite.  Declare it as:

```
reg [7:0] j; // 0 to 255
```

or as

```
integer j;
```